# Does the VxWorks sockLib support the SO_RCVTIMEO option that can be used by setsockopt to set the timeout of a recv call like in winsock?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, vxworks

Does the VxWorks sockLib support the SO_RCVTIMEO option that can be used by setsockopt to set the timeout of a recv call like in winsock?

Here is an example of the call in Windows:

```
int timeout = 30000; // 30 seconds
status = setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(int));
```

The confusing thing about this is that the status returned by setsockopt does not indicate an error from an unknown option and SO_RCVTIMEO is defined in sockets.h. The call still does not produce the desired action though and I can't find any documentation saying that it is supported.

If it is not supported, any suggestions for an equivalent approach?

I am using VxWorks 5.4. I would be interested to know if it works in a later version.

Comment: I'm not sure, but here is one thing to consider.  While Windows sets SO_RCVTIMEO with a DWORD, most UNIX use a struct timeval.  Maybe this is the issue?  What happens if you try:   struct timeval tv; tv.tv_sec = 30; setsockopt(sockid, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,(char*)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have tried this previously with no improvement.

Comment: According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/comp.os.vxworks/JztxIuX6oOU) the answer is no.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot answer this question directly, but I can say that to solve these types of "blocking receive" style problems, use the select() function to specify a timeout while waiting on incoming socket data. Then you can avoid the blocking recv() call entirely until you know there is data available in the socket.

I recommend this solution for VxWorks (#include "selectLib.h") as well as for Linux and Windows socket libraries. SO_RCVTIMEO is useful, but [select](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~courses/ee8205/Data-Sheets/Tornado-VxWorks/vxworks/ref/selectLib.html#select)() is even more useful, across all operating systems.

Comment: This recommendation is directly contradicted [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/comp.os.vxworks/JztxIuX6oOU).